# Python: Module returning "None" values into created file

Tags: python

I'm stuck with my program.  Basically I have to call a module and have that module create a file with values that I refer back to later on in program.  However, the module doesn't work correctly and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  Thanks in advance.  Here is my current program.

```
import math
import mymath

def main():

    getData()
    summer()

def getData():
    powerfile = open("myfile.dat","w")
    fin = open("sample.dat","r")
    done = False
    while not done:
        x = int(fin.readline())
        if x < 0:
            done = True
        else:
            y = int(fin.readline())
            answer = mymath.powerval(x,y)
            answer = str(answer)+'\n'
            powerfile.write(answer)
    powerfile.close()

def summer():
    file_in = open("myfile.dat","r")
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for a in file_in:
        number = int(a)
        count += 1
        total += number
    file_in.close()
    print("The final sum was", total)   

    close = input('')

main()
```

And my mymath module:

```
import math

def powerval(x,y):
    if x > y:
        big = x
    else:
        small = x
    if x > y:
        small = y
    else:
        big = y
    answer = pow(big, small)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `powerval` function has no return statement.

```
def powerval(x,y):
    if x > y:
        big = x
    else:
        small = x
    if x > y:
        small = y
    else:
        big = y
    answer = pow(big, small)
    return answer # <----
```